# How to hide cmd in a command executed by a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am making a code that opens an exe and it writes a text, but I just want it to write the text after the exe close
I have tryed this :

```
start /wait WindowsFormsApp12.exe
start C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\teste.vbs
```

It works but it shows cmd.
I do not want it to show cmd.

This is what is written on vbs:

```
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{d}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{o}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{c}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{u}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{m}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{n}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{t}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{o}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{-}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{n}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{t}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{r}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{p}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{o}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{t}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{m}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
```

Comment: @Brien I don´t wanna hide the text I want to hide the cmd .

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way. (Or probably better, write the whole thing in vbs instead of batch.)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: if that is right, then your link above should answer the question.

Comment: @Stephan DodgyCodeException is right.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, Pedro: cleaned up comments. You may also want to remove now unneeded comments.

Comment: As has already been mentioned, you can run the executable and wait for it to finish if that's what you need, _(although it seems more like you're wanting it to stay open so that you can send your text string to it with sendkeys)_, immediately before those sendkeys instructions within the same VBScript. As your question currently stands, I see no need for the batch file at all.

Comment: @Compo how can i make wait for me to close the exe with vbs?

Comment: send keystrokes `ALT`, `F`ile E`X`it (depends on the menu of your exe)

Comment: That's a different question **and tag**, and can depend very much on the specific executable you're wanting to run!

Comment: @Compo I wanna run a c# form exe

Comment: It makes no difference to me, write the vbscript code to run an exe as you want and try it. If it doesn't do what you want, edit your question and its code to suit and change the tag so that VBScript interested parties may see it and possibly help.

Comment: The way your batch file is currently written, it starts the C# executable, waits for it to exit (you'll have to exit it manually) and then runs the vbs which sends keystrokes to the batch file window. Surely that's not what you want.